# In spite of proper permission not being able to cat the file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, permissions, acl

I want to cat `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf` which has `0600` permission.

```
λ ubuntu [~] → sudo stat /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf
  File: ‘/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf’
  Size: 9398        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 529194      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1001/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1001/  ubuntu)
Access: 2017-01-23 17:10:31.170988382 +0000
Modify: 2017-01-23 17:10:23.107069483 +0000
Change: 2017-01-23 18:47:55.460216373 +0000
 Birth: -
```

but when I try to cat it, I get permission denied!

```
λ ubuntu [~] → who am i
ubuntu   pts/0        2017-01-23 15:27 (10.0.2.2)

λ ubuntu [~] → cat /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf
cat: /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf: Permission denied
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the permissions for this directory `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg`?

Comment: it's `0600` sorry, my bad, I'm gonna make it 0700. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the permissions on the `.gnupg` directory are missing the `x` permissions, which allows traversing to the `gpg.conf` file and its visibility.

Try this:

```
sudo chmod u+x /home/ubuntu/.gnupg
```

Answer (score 0):

MAC tools can also cause similiar behavior.
Always check selinux or apparmor in such cases where DAC allows access, but it's still forbidden.